# Topology rules with attribute table exceptions in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, topology

I have a set of geometries that represent different surveying polygons, for each set I have certain features that are exactly the same geometry wise, but have a different value in a unique identifier I have created in the attribute table to identify each survey separately (so, for example, one polygon that is right next to another will share a common vertex point, and in that spot there will be two different points with the same geometry but a different value on the attribute table identifier field).

When I'm checking for topology errors I always look for overlapping features, but I find myself getting multiple "fake" errors due to having to place 2 points in the same spot.

Is there a way to make it so that the topology rules check the attribute table for features that overlap, and only considers it errors when they have the same value in the identifier column?.

Comment: Have you explored the [Find Identical](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm) tool? You can test on geometry and attributes

Comment: @Hornbydd This does work to identify If I have repeated by mistake the same category on a given point, but when I run the topology it will be marked as an error regardless. However if you use the tool you mention to identify that indeed every point with equal geometry has a different identifier, and filter for unique geometries only, that would basically be the equivalent of what i'm trying to achieve. 

If you wanna make it an official answer I will consider it resolved with that, thanks!

Comment: I am not quite following this. Topology runs against every record, ignoring filters. After you get errors, you can select the records and do additional filtering. Then, mark some as exceptions. Many topology errors are not true errors (or "fake" as you say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other apparent smooth way of acomplishing this, a good way to solve it is to use the [Find Identical tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm) In conjunction with the [Delete Identifcal tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete-identical.htm). So the workflow is to essentially:

1. Check whether or not there's features with the same geometry and same value for the identification field (In my case I have an integer that represents the ID of the survey in my worlkflow based on location and date) with `Find Identical`.
2. Fix any errors you've found so that any features with the same geometries have a different identifier
3. Run the `Delete Identical` to delete duplicate geometries.
4. Run topology rules as usual

That way you're not getting any potential errors from geometries that are intentionally the same (and thus, overlap, intersect, and so on).

This was basically answered by another user in the comments before but since he doesn't seem to want to answer I figured I'd do so.